How to run an init script from correct volume when using databricks asset bundles
I have the following resource definition. What i am trying to do is attaching an aws profile to a cluster so it can pull python packages from private codeArtifact via pip. However, in order to allow then pip to pull, I need a init script. But its impossible to figure out in the docs what the config for this is.
resources:
  jobs:
    staging-test:
      name: staging-test
      email_notifications:
        on_failure:
          - ${var.mail}
      description: Staging job for ${var.package}
      tags:
        stage: "staging"
        version: ${var.package}
        tasks:
        - task_key: test-from-wheel
          python_wheel_task:
            entry_point: run # Entry point of the wheel
            package_name: # Same as in setup py of wheel
            parameters: ["-a", "test_run", "-m", "model"]
          depends_on:
            - task_key: test-from-wheel
          new_cluster:
            init_scripts:
              - volumes:
                  destination: dbfs://Workspace/Users/Myself/init.sh
            instance_pool_id: ${var.instance-pool-id}
            spark_version: 15.4.x-scala2.12
            autoscale:
              min_workers: 1
              max_workers: 4
            aws_attributes:
              instance_profile_arn: ${var.aws_instance-profile-codeartifact-access}
          libraries:
            # Using the wheel file from code artifact
            - pypi:
                package: ${var.package}
                repo: ${var.codeartifact-repo}

I already searched the internet on how to properly attach init script to clusters in asset bundles

Ok, after some more search and try and error i figured it out. init scripts must be on volumes. that the same as in the UI.
here is the correct job
resources:
  jobs:
    staging-test:
      name: staging-test
      email_notifications:
        on_failure:
          - ${var.mail}
      description: Staging job for ${var.package}
      tags:
        stage: "staging"
        version: ${var.package}
        tasks:
        - task_key: test-from-wheel
          python_wheel_task:
            entry_point: run # Entry point of the wheel
            package_name: # Same as in setup py of wheel
            parameters: ["-a", "test_run", "-m", "model"]
          depends_on:
            - task_key: test-from-wheel
          new_cluster:
            init_scripts:
              - volumes: # Only Unity catalog volumes or s3 are supported
                  destination: /Volumes/catalog/schema/scripts/aws-codeartifacts-init.sh
            instance_pool_id: ${var.instance-pool-id}
            spark_version: 15.4.x-scala2.12
            autoscale:
              min_workers: 1
              max_workers: 4
            aws_attributes:
              instance_profile_arn: ${var.aws_instance-profile-codeartifact-access}
          libraries:
            # Using the wheel file from code artifact
            - pypi:
                package: ${var.package}
                repo: ${var.codeartifact-repo}

This blog post gave me the final hing. but i could have infered likely as well from the databricks api doc with a little more digging.
https://medium.com/marvelous-mlops/dealing-with-private-python-packages-in-databricks-asset-bundles-part-1-45b9d024d7a9
